# Where can I find the Dell XPS package archives, and the right packages to install?

Tags: apt, package-management, dell

I just got a new Dell XPS 13 9300 today. It came with Ubuntu 18.04, but wanting a newer OS, and having a 20.04 USB disk lying around, I wiped it and installed 20.04.

But now I see that Dell has some of its own package archives. I think I found them here:

http://dell.archive.canonical.com/dists/

What I think I figured out so far is: 20.04 is "focal," I think.

I followed the advice [here](https://medium.com/@nrogap/dell-repository-for-install-additional-drivers-on-ubuntu-4cf061640180), replacing the distro codename with "focal" where necessary. And now my /etc/apt/sources.list has:

```
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates focal-dell public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates focal-dell public
```

So far so good. But do I need to know the code name of my machine? And now that I have these package archive sources installed, how can I find the packages I need to install?

More generally, how do I find a list of packages stored or served by a given package archive?

Comment: Only just started looking into this stuff myself, but it looks like Dell haven't put anything for 20.04 there yet.

They're shipping XPS machines with 20.04 on now (not Precisions though, annoyingly) so you might be able to get the ready-to-go version of 20.04 from their support site: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk?app=drivers

Comment: Sorry, this is the bit of the support site you'll need to try, not the one I linked before: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/drivers/osiso

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out: https://github.com/jules-ch/Ubuntu20-Setup-XPS13/blob/master/setup.sh
It works for me

Comment: Nice find.  It's a bit much to use as-it, but is a useful reference.  Looks like the Dell Fossa repo's live now.